# Why is it written in nmap official doc that -sL does not send any packet, when it actually send them?

Tags: networking, security, nmap

Sniffing with wireshark, I see a bunch of ARP and DNS requests.
So why in the official doc it's written this:

> The list scan is a degenerate form of host discovery that simply lists
> each host of the network(s) specified, without sending any packets to
> the target hosts. By default, Nmap still does reverse-DNS resolution
> on the hosts to learn their names. It is often surprising how much
> useful information simple hostnames give out. For example, fw.chi is
> the name of one company's Chicago firewall. Nmap also reports the
> total number of IP addresses at the end. The list scan is a good
> sanity check to ensure that you have proper IP addresses for your
> targets. If the hosts sport domain names you do not recognize, it is
> worth investigating further to prevent scanning the wrong company's
> network.
>
> Since the idea is to simply print a list of target hosts, options for higher level functionality such as port scanning, OS detection, or
> host discovery cannot be combined with this. If you wish to disable
> host discovery while still performing such higher level functionality,
> read up on the -Pn (skip host discovery) option.

Comment: Well, show the command you run and tje packets you see sent?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1813916/why-is-it-written-in-nmap-official-doc-that-sl-does-not-send-any-packet-when-i

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is correct:

> The list scan is a degenerate form of host discovery that simply lists each host of the network(s) specified, without sending any packets **to the target hosts**. By default, Nmap still does reverse-DNS resolution on the hosts to learn their names.

(Emphasis mine)

Just because we're doing DNS resolution queries doesn't mean we're sending packets to the target hosts that we're asking the names / IP addresses of.

Comment: but I also see ARP requests with target the ip target host. and also ICMP packets.

Comment: The ARP packets may be the result of the DNS queries. Are the ICMP packets coming from the host running NMAP? Are there other processes that might be pinging the target hosts at the same time as your NMAP scan?

Comment: sorry, it turns out icmp packets are not created by nmap, they must come from other source.

anyway, if it should only do a reverse-DNS resolution, why does it send arp requests? it sends an ARP requests to each of the hosts specified in nmap command (I gave in input a /24 subnet), so it actually "talks" with the target, since the targets will respond to the ARP request

Comment: I mentioned the ARP requests as a result of DNS requests only as a theory. They are actually a definite result of the ICMP packets - ARP is how the switches know which port(s) to send the ICMP packets to. Actually, that's true for any communications on the network - ARP packets tell the switches which MAC address has which IP.

Comment: A monitoring system that warns the network (or server) administrators that a server is down would be a likely source of ICMP pings, which, as already pointed out, will usually trigger ARP requests for the target's mac address.  Some or all of the ICMP and ARP traffic may have no connection at all to your `nmap` commands.